# Understanding how to do something when an event handler has finished, Android, Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am fairly new to Android/Java/Firebase so may be on the wrong track here, feel free to steer me in any direction...

I am trying to understand simply how to "do something" ***after*** an event handler has completed its job....

Specifically, I am trying to "cleanly" enscapulate firebase object management.  I have a local object (User, for this example) that contains user data.  A subset(subclass) of the user data is stored on Firebase.  That is to say the balance of the User Object Data is stored only locally, because I can either calculate it an runtime, or otherwise it is not reasonable or required to store that data on Firebase. (This detail I think is irrelevant to the actual question)

The subclass (UserFireBase) is designed so it can be directly read to/from Firebase in one line using the buit in JSON Serialiser. Example below:

```
public Class User{
  String UserID
  Image userPhoto; //example of locally held User data
  Boolean dataReadComplete=false;//a very poor locking device
  public Class UserFirebase {//User Data stored on a Firebase Node
    String UserName
    String UserWebsiteURL
  } 

public void writeUserDatatoFB(){ 
  refUserTree = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + "Users");
  refUserTree.child(UserID).setValue(UserFirebase);//this works just fine
}



public void readUserDataFromFB(){
  refUserTree = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + "Users");
  dataReadComplete=false;
  refUserTree.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      UserFirebase = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserFirebase.class);
      dataReadComplete=true;
    }
  @Override
  public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}});
```

So this does work, from the main activity I can effectively go:

```
user.readUserDataFromFB();

//wait until dataReadComplete=true, then do some stuff

user.writeDataToFB();
```

But it just seems wrong, and ugly design.  i.e what is the Best Practice to have code execute after a one-time event handler is complete? e.g in other languages I might be able to pass in a method-as-a-parameter to the WriteUserData function, so that when it is finished, it calls the next bit of code I need to execute...

The only other solution I can currently think of is to move the WriteUserData code into my main activity, which also seems kind of ugly, not-encapsulated.

Is my general design utterly wrong here? I am not at all well acquainted with event driven programming.

(thankyou)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java supports callbacks too. In fact, that `ValueEventListener` you're passing in is a form of callback. So if you want to execute the write operation after the data has loaded:

```
user.readUserDataFromFirebase(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        user.writeDataToFirebase();
    }
});

public void readUserDataFromFirebase(Runnable onLoaded){
    refUserTree = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + "Users");
    refUserTree.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserFirebase = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserFirebase.class);
            onLoaded.run();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
    });
};
```

It feels pretty non-OO this way, so I'd just make them static functions and pass the user in:

```
readUserDataFromFirebase(new UnaryOperator<UserFirebase>() {
    public UserFirebase apply(UserFirebase user) {
        user.writeDataToFirebase();
    }
});

public static void readUserDataFromFirebase(String userID, UnaryOperator<UserFirebase> onLoaded){
    refUserTree = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + "Users");
    refUserTree.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserFirebase user = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserFirebase.class);
            onLoaded.apply(user);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
    });
};
```

You could also look into [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)s, which are the Java class that deals with asynchronous loading situations such as this one. They're the Java equivalent to the JavaScript Promises that are getting much use these days.